# Choose the next number from columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
ID     Op     Cl     V        C   R0   R1   R2   R3   R4   R5
UN   22.85  22.86  8830500  0.21  25   34   12   87   105  102
SS   55.01  52.67  6500     5.45  84   122  147  124  644  788   
PN   90.00  90.99  1000     102   89   55   100  156  44   87     
PI   184.99 182.38 15000    84    56   77   97   45   44   33
```

I want to make a new column that shows the next biggest value after `'Cl'` within the `R0,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5` columns. Following is my intended result:

```
ID     Op     Cl     V        C   R0   R1   R2   R3   R4   R5  X
UN  22.85  22.86  8830500  0.21   25   34   12   87   105  102 25
SS   55.01  52.67  6500     5.45  84   122  147  124  644  788 84  
PN   90.00  90.99  1000     102   89   55   100  156  44   87 100   
PI   184.99 182.38 15000    84    56   77   97   45   44   33 NaN
```

I have been researching it a little but no luck. Some help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Why there's 84 for ID `SS` (isn't the greatest value = 788)? What about NaN for ID `PI`?

Comment: For SS (52.67) the next in line is 84, not 788. It has to choose the next value in line. For PI (182.38) non of the R columns have values that are bigger than that therefore NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what do you mean by the next biggest. If you mean by the order from `R0->R5` we can try `idxmax`:

```
# extract the `R` columns
s = df.filter(like='R')

# find out where these columns are larger than `Cl`:
mask = s.gt(df['Cl'], axis='rows')

# extract the values with `idxmax` and `lookup`:
df['X'] = np.where(mask.any(1), s.lookup(s.index,mask.idxmax(1)), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   ID      Op      Cl        V       C  R0   R1   R2   R3   R4   R5      X
0  UN   22.85   22.86  8830500    0.21  25   34   12   87  105  102   25.0
1  SS   55.01   52.67     6500    5.45  84  122  147  124  644  788   84.0
2  PN   90.00   90.99     1000  102.00  89   55  100  156   44   87  100.0
3  PI  184.99  182.38    15000   84.00  56   77   97   45   44   33    NaN
```

---

If by next biggest, you mean in terms of the values, we can modify the above with `sort`:

```
# extract and sort by rows
s = np.sort(df.filter(like='R').values, axis=1)

# now we work with numpy data:
mask = s > df['Cl'].values[:,None]

# check and assign
df['X'] = np.where(mask.any(1), s[np.arange(s.shape[0]),mask.argmax(1)], np.nan)
```

Then you pretty much have the same output (for this sample data), but of course with the said meaning.

Comment: Hey, it works like a charm! And yes by 'next biggest' i mean the values. One small question tho, what if I want X to show values that are near to 2% from Cl (in any direction) and not just the values that are next in line. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not really *small* :-), but it's very similar to what you ask here. Use `-` instead of `>` to compute the difference, then divide by `s` for the percentage. From there, you can compare with a threshold much like when you define `mask`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
def func(x):
    R_values = x[1:]
    idx_greater = R_values > x[0]
    return np.where(idx_greater.any(), R_values[idx_greater].min(), np.nan)

df['X'] = df.filter(regex='Cl|^R').apply(func, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ID      Op      Cl        V       C  R0   R1   R2   R3   R4   R5      X
0  UN   22.85   22.86  8830500    0.21  25   34   12   87  105  102   25.0
1  SS   55.01   52.67     6500    5.45  84  122  147  124  644  788   84.0
2  PN   90.00   90.99     1000  102.00  89   55  100  156   44   87  100.0
3  PI  184.99  182.38    15000   84.00  56   77   97   45   44   33    nan
```

This is probably a bit slower and less elegant than @Quang Hoang approach.

The logic behind this is applying per row a function that verifies if there is any R value greater than the value in `Cl` column, then get the minimum value for those values, returning NaN otherwise.

**Note:** `Cl` column should be before the `R` columns, as the data you've provided.